# Alter/Change Nth Element of Cell Value Excel VBA

Tags: string, vba, excel, case-sensitive

I was creating a macro to reverse the capitalization of cell values, to explain better.

Original values-

```
hh3crd220
xmi4Idc200
TEst02NoW
```

Output-

```
HH3CRD220
XMI4iDC200
teST02nOw
```

I think there must already be macros which would do the job, but i was coding one myself, everything works fine except changing the nth value, **Mid** is not working since it will only extract the value, i tried **Character** but that will only format the element, i wanted something like character.value or mid.value function to work.

```
Sub CapsChange()
Dim letr As String
Dim Val1 As String

Dim sr As Range
lastrow = ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveSheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

Set sr = Range("A1:A" & lastrow)

For Each r In sr
Fval = r.Value
Val1 = Left(r.Value, 1)

If Val1 <> UCase(Val1) Then

For i = 1 To Len(Fval)
    letr = Mid(Fval, i, 1)
    If letr = UCase(letr) Then

**'First Code try**
    letr = LCase(letr)
**'Second Code try**
    r.Characters(i, 1).Value = LCase(letr)
    Else
    letr = UCase(letr)
    r.Characters(i, 1).Value = UCase(letr)
    End If
Next i

End If

Next

End Sub
```

Just Need Help changing/controlling the nth character of cell value, like we use cell(x,y).value = XXX.

Comment: It would be easier to have a function for this rather that doing all of it in a single sub. And the best way for this would be to use another variable to accumulate characters and then put that variable in the cell! ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

**variant 1 using SUB()**

```
Sub Test()
    Dim rng As Range, cl As Range, i&
    Set rng = Range("A1:A" & Cells(ActiveSheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)
    For Each cl In rng.Cells
        For i = Len(cl.Value) To 1 Step -1
            With cl.Characters(i, 1)
                If .Text = UCase(.Text) Then
                    .Text = LCase(.Text)
                ElseIf .Text = LCase(.Text) Then
                    .Text = UCase(.Text)
                End If
            End With
    Next i, cl
End Sub
```

**variant 2 using Function()**

```
Public Function ReverseCase(cl As Range)
    Dim StringOutput$, i&
    For i = Len(cl.Value) To 1 Step -1
        With cl.Characters(i, 1)
            If .Text = UCase(.Text) Then
                StringOutput = LCase(.Text) & StringOutput
            ElseIf .Text = LCase(.Text) Then
                StringOutput = UCase(.Text) & StringOutput
            End If
        End With
    Next i
    ReverseCase = StringOutput
End Function
```

*test for function()*

[image]

both variants are tested, works fine

Comment: Hey, Sorry for late response, your code worked like a charm and i really liked the concept of using function to complete the job.

Answer (score 1):

Something like the below function would be far easier to re-use!

Here is how to use it :

```
Option Explicit

Sub test_Angad_Arora()
Dim wS As Worksheet, _
    LastRow As Long, _
    i As Long

Set wS = ActiveSheet
With wS
    LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 1 To LastRow
        .Cells(i, 1) = InvertCaseCore(.Cells(i, 1))
    Next i
End With
End Sub
```

And the function that invert the capatilization of the inputed string:

```
Public Function InvertCaseCore(StringToReCapitalize As String)

Dim l As Integer, _
    c As String, _
    OutPut As String, _
    i As Integer

l = Len(StringToReCapitalize)
For i = 1 To l
     c = Mid(StringToReCapitalize, i, 1)
     If (c >= "A") And (c <= "Z") Then
         c = LCase(c)
     ElseIf (c >= "a") And (c <= "z") Then
         c = UCase(c)
     End If
     OutPut = OutPut & c
 Next i

    InvertCaseCore = OutPut
End Function
```

Comment: Hey, Sorry for late response, it worked perfectly. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`Mid` **statement**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/gg264462.aspx) , which allows in place modification of a string:

```
Sub CapsChange()
    Dim letr As String
    Dim Val1 As String

    Dim sr As Range
    lastrow = ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveSheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    Set sr = Range("A1:A" & lastrow)

    For Each r In sr
        Fval = r.Value
        Val1 = Left(r.Value, 1)

        If Val1 <> UCase(Val1) Then

            For i = 1 To Len(Fval)
                letr = Mid(Fval, i, 1)
                If letr = UCase(letr) Then
                    Mid(Fval,i,1) = LCase(letr)
                else
                    Mid(Fval,i,1) = UCase(letr)
                End If
            Next i

        End If

    Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

You're looking for the `replace`-Function ([See this link](http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/replace_vba.php)).
An example:

```
Replace("abCabCde", "C", "c", , 1)
```

This will find the first (and only the first) occurrence of "C" in "abCabCde" and replaces it with "c" to get "abcabCde".

Comment: @R3uK Since he already managed to identify the case of each letter, replacing that letter with its altered version shouldn't be so hard any more.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. Take `cccCCC` for example. Once `C` is replaced with `c`, you get `cccccc`. Where do you go from there? Dead end.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisCorbett OP already built a loop through a string, looked at each letter and determined its case. Using that, `cccCCC` would turn to `CccCCC` to `CCcCCC` to `CCCCCC`to `CCCcCC`... I did not provide a full solution in full conscience, since OP 1. didn't ask for one, but only for help with this specific step and 2. OP seems competent enough to build this into his own solution.

Comment: Ok... it's still not clear to me how an implementation using `Replace` would work. Once you've replaced the first occurrence, how will you replace further occurrences? And what about other letters than "c"? By the way, the link is dead.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisCorbett I fixed the link, thank you. Regarding your question: You loop through the word via `For i = 1 To Len(Fval)`, determine the case of `letr = Mid(Fval, i, 1)` and then `Replace((Fval, letr, Ucase(letr), , 1)` (for a lowercase `letr`). All these elements (except `Replace`, obviously) were already part of the question, so I just answered with the last neccessary detail.

Comment: To me this is not a sensible use of `Replace`. What this function does is *search* and replace... No point in searching if you're cycling through the string one character at a time.  Anyway, it doesn't look like the implementation you describe would achieve the desired result: it will only ever replace the first occurrence of a letter within the string. Sorry, I've spent some time considering your answer and still don't get where you're going.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95695/discussion-between-verzweifler-and-jean-francois-corbett).